# Añadir CASE en una query

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando adaptar una query para controlar los datos de salida.
La siguiente linea me 4 diferentes metodos de pago, pero me gustaria tener la salida de forma mas vistual:

```
  REPLACE(
    max(
    CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' 
    and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END
    ), 
    'redsys', 
    'VISA'
  ) AS payment_method,
```

Para ello, quiero anidar las siguientes lineas para añadir un case/reemplazo según el texto que me devuelve la anterior linea. Por ejemplo con los siguientes WHEN:

```
('redsys') THEN 'VISA'
('cod') THEN 'REMBOLSO'
('cheque') THEN 'BIZUM'
('bacs') THEN 'TRANSFERENCIA'
```

Como lo anido o como se estructura para añadir mas condiciones?

Gracias!

Comment: Ya sabes cómo funcionamos: debes intentar algo y mostrar el código, su error, el dataset y que esperabas obtener

Answer (score 0):

encontré la solución. Añadí la estructura siguiente:

```
  max(
    CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN 

    CASE 
    WHEN pm.meta_value = 'redsys' THEN 'VISA'
        WHEN pm.meta_value = 'cod' THEN 'REMBOLSO'
        WHEN pm.meta_value = 'cheque' THEN 'BIZUM'
        WHEN pm.meta_value = 'bacs' THEN 'TRANSFERENCIA'
        ELSE '' END
END
  ) AS payment_method
```